# Does delayed_job work for rails3? which version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

when i run rails g delayed_job,i always get the "Couldn't find generator delayed_job",i already add the "get "delayed_job"" to my gemfile...

is there someone tell me why? how can i resolve this problem,thanks...

Now the delayed_job is fully supported with rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's works on 2.1.0.pre2 version

In your gemfile you can put

```
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.0.pre2'
```

Comment: well the delayed_job is working,but i always get this error:Job failed to load: uninitialized constant MailingJob!! should i require this file in the lib??

Comment: it's another problem. Can you launch another question with more information.

Comment: here is my another thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929232/rake-jobswork-error-uninitialized-constant ,thanks!