# rake jobs:work error, uninitialized constant 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

i am using delayed_job 2.1.0.pre2,
and in my lib i have a class which named MailingJob(mailing_job.rb),and it has one method named perform.
In my controller , i put a new MailingJob object in my delayed_job queue as the doc said.
but when i run the "rake jobs:work" command,it always told me that it can't find "MailingJob", is it necessary to require the mailing_job.rb file?if yes,where should i put this?
thanks!

Comment: It's virtually impossible to help you without better information. We really need to see code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mailing_job.rb` must be in a place where Rails can find and auto-load it. Where do you have that file? Unless it's in `app/models` or something like that, it won't find it on its own.

I have my jobs in `app/jobs` but this works because I added that path to the Rails load paths in the `environment.rb` `Rails::Initializer.run` block:

```
config.load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/jobs"
```

Comment: good clue,i put the "mailing_job.rb" into my RAILSAPP/lib directory, i thought it would be loaded automatically,would the lib directory load auto when the rails run?

Comment: No, `lib` isn't in the load paths by default. You could add an initializer to require your things from lib though.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays in Rails 6.1 I had to put it in the `application.rb` as follows:

```rb
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('/app/jobs')
```